# If $X_t$ is a AR(2)-process, what is $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$?

Tags: time-series

Q: If $X_t$ is a AR(2)-process, what is $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$?

$X_t$ is a AR(2)-process if it's stationary and satisfies $X_t = \phi_1 X_{t-1} + \phi_2 X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_t$ is white noise.

One may elaborate \begin{equation}\begin{split} Y_t &= X_t - X_{t-1}\\ &= \phi_1 X_{t-1} + (\phi_2 - \phi_1) X_{t-2} - \phi_2 X_{t-3} + \epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1} \\
&=(\phi_1B +(\phi_2 - \phi_1)B^2 - \phi_2B^3)X_t + (1-B)\epsilon_t \end{split}\end{equation}

But I don't know the benefit.

I have the following options:

1. $Y_t$ is an ARMA(2,1)-process
2. $Y_t$ is an AR(2)-process
3. $Y_t$ is an MA(2)-process
4. $Y_t$ is an AR(3)-process

Comment: $$X_t = \phi_1 X_{t - 1} + \phi_2 X_{t - 2} + \epsilon_t$$

This is AR(2) model, not MA(2) model

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's supposed to be a AR(2) model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
     \begin{align*}
            X_t &= \phi_1  X_{t - 1} + \phi_2 X_{t - 2} + \epsilon_t\\
            X_{t - 1} &= \phi_1 X_{t - 2} + \phi_2 X_{t - 3} + \epsilon_{t - 1}
     \end{align*}
$$

which implies
$$
       X_t - X_{t - 1} = \phi_1(X_{t - 1} - X_{t - 2}) + \phi_2(X_{t - 2} - X_{t - 3}) + \epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t - 1}
$$
or
$$
      (1 - \phi_1 B - \phi_2 B^2)Y_t = (1 - B)\epsilon_t
$$

Consider these cases:

- If $\phi_1 + \phi_2 = 1$,

  - If $\phi_1 = 1, \phi_2 = 0$, then $(Y_t)$ is the white noise
  - Otherwise, $(Y_t)$ is AR(1)
- If $\phi_1 + \phi_2 \neq 1$, then the model cannot be simplified and we have ARMA(2, 1)